Unique continuation of Laplace eigenforms
Let $M$ be a compact Riemannian manifold and $\Delta = d\delta + \delta d$ denote the (positive definite) Hodge Laplacian acting on differential forms. Call a smooth differential form $\omega$ a Laplace eigenform if there exists a non-negative $\lambda$ such that $\Delta \omega = \lambda\omega$. By elliptic regularity, eigenforms are smooth a posteriori.
One version of unique continuation principle for Laplace eigenfunctions is that the order of vanishing of eigenfunctions at any point is finite. I was wondering if there is some interpretation of the unique continuation principle for Laplace eigenforms. Philosophically, I am not even sure what is the analogue of "zero set of a function" for differential forms. This is just an exercise in curiosity, and I apologize for the somewhat vague question.
